# Не подсвечивается следующий(2017) год в календаре

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

проблема в выделении дат 2017 году, дело в том что оно не присваивает класс на следующий год.
наше похожую проблему но как реализовать
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213408/jquery-datepicker-beforeshowday-not-working-for-2014

```js
 var active_dates = ["11/12/2016",  "13/12/2016", "01/01/2017", "15/01/2017", "16/01/2017"];
 
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
   
   todayHighlight: true,
   maxViewMode: 0,
    beforeShowMonth: 1,
 

   beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var d = date;
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear() ;
            if(curr_month<10)curr_month = "0"+curr_month;
                if(curr_date<10)curr_date = "0"+curr_month;
    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

      if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
       return {
       classes: 'booked '
       };
      }
     return;
    }
   });
```

```css
.booked{
 background: #F00!important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что номера месяцев в шаблонах (active_dates) начинаются с нуля, а в коде проверки - нет. И решение будет такое же, как в "похожей проблеме".

Грязный быстрофикс. Вставьте вот это после `var curr_year = d.getFullYear();`:

```
if(curr_month<10)curr_month = "0"+curr_month;
if(curr_date<10)curr_date = "0"+curr_month;
```